# Batch Script not choosing correct condition

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Trying to write a batch script to get remaining **Physical memory** on a **Windows** machine. And based on condition specified, it will give me option to open task manager, if memory available is below the specified limit. 
Even though if condition is satisfied, Output always shows else. Sometimes, output becomes unpredictable, as it may go both ways!

please suggest necessary changes to achieve the desired output.

```
@echo off
mode con:cols=55 lines=8
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic os get freephysicalmemory') do (set m=%%p
goto :done)

:done
set /a FreeMem = %m%/1000
if  %FreeMem% LEQ "900"( goto :error ) ELSE ( goto :go )

:go
COLOR 2F
echo Hi %username%!
echo Remaining Free Memory is ---%FreeMem% MB---
echo It's safe to go ahead!
goto :cont

:error
COLOR 4F
echo Hey %username%!
echo Remaining Free Memory is ONLY --- %FreeMem% MB---
echo It's not safe to go ahead!
goto :ask

:ask
echo Do you want me to open Task Manager for you? (y/n)
set  INPUT=
set /p INPUT=Type input: %=%
If  /I  "%INPUT%"=="y" goto :yes
If  /I "%INPUT%" =="n" goto :no
echo Incorrect Input & goto :ask

:yes 
TASKMGR
goto cont

:no
echo AS you Wish!
goto cont

:cont
pause
```

Comment: Based on the color editing of SO I would say, that you commented a big part of your code. I am not sure tho; you might want to check that. It would fit your description as you perfectly put together `It *comment* s not safe to [...]`

Does it say `Hi [...] NOT safe` ?


If that is not the problem you might want to echo the value of `%FreeMem%` Before you get to the condition to check for other errors.

Comment: how do you define "remaining Physical memory"? ;) also, the question doesn't seem to be PoSh related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the quotation marks around the memory number.  It is being read as a string instead of a number.

```
if  %FreeMem% LEQ 900 ( goto :error ) ELSE ( goto :go )
```

instead of

```
if  %FreeMem% LEQ "900" ( goto :error ) ELSE ( goto :go )
```

Comment: You need a space between 900 and the parentheses.

Comment: Though, it worked for me,  would be very helpful to know why the output was abrupt and sometimes, even colors declared in 'if' was shown in 'else' and vice-versa! (I am clear with number-string complications, but would like to know the flow while colors were exchanged!)